# Merging (logical OR) together the contents of two 'bitmaps' in strings

Tags: python, string, bitmap, logical-operators

I've got two strings that contains 'bitmaps' of weekdays: for example, `1------` is Monday only, `--3-5--` is Wednesday and Friday, you get the idea.

I'd like to merge these together with the equivalent of a logical OR, so that eg. `1------` || `--3-5--` = `1-3-5--`.  What's the most Pythonic way to do this?  I'm currently doing this, but it doesn't feel particularly elegant:

```
week1, week2, merged = '1------', '--3-5--', ''
for i in range(0, len(week1)):
  merged += week1[i] if week1[i] != '-' else week2[i]
print merged
```

Note that I'm using Python 2.7, so no mutable strings, and it's safe to assume that the input strings are always correctly formatted (= always use `-` for false and `1..7` in the correct position for true).

Comment: I think it's hard to get a Pythonic solution, because strings don't make an especially good data structure for holding this kind of data. Perhaps you could store your week days in sets instead? Then you can just do `merged = week1 | week2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the builtins `map`, `max` and `zip`:

```
>>> week1, week2 = '1------', '--3-5--'
>>> ''.join(map(max, zip(week1, week2)))
'1-3-5--'
```

This works because:

- `zip` returns tuples of the n'th character from each string `[('1', '-'), ('-'. '-'), ... ]`
- `max` returns `-` from a tuple if and only if all entries are `-`. This is because `-` is sorted lower than digit characters, e.g. `max('1', '-') == '1'`.
- `map` applies `max` to each tuple in the zipped list, producing a list of maximum characters.
- `''.join` links together the list of maximum characters, produced using `map`, using the empty string.

This expression also works if you have more than two week strings:

```
>>> week3 = '------7'
>>> ''.join(map(max, zip(week1, week2, week3)))
'1-3-5-7'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> ''.join(b if a == '-' else a for a, b in zip('1------', '--3-5--'))
'1-3-5--'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generalise this to a function that works for any number of *weeks*, eg:

```
week1, week2, week3 = '1------', '--3-5--', '---4--6-'

def bitor_weeks(*args):
    days = set().union(*args).difference('-')
    return ''.join(ch if ch in days else '-' for ch in '1234567')

print bitor_weeks(week1, week2, week3)
```

---

Or go for the whole hog and enable all bitwise ops on it, eg:

```
class WeekSet(set):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        days = set().union(*args).difference('-')
        if days.difference('1234567-'):
            raise ValueError('inputs must be 1-7 or -')
        set.__init__(self, days)
    def __repr__(self):
        return ''.join(ch if ch in self else '-' for ch in '1234567')


week1, week2, week3 = '1------', '--3-5--', '-2-4--7'
t1 = WeekSet(week1, week2)
# 1-3-5--
print WeekSet('456') & t1
# ----5--
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit heavier, but you may have more than 2 "week" strings

```
''.join(filter(lambda l: l!='-', lst)[0] if set(lst) != set(['-']) else '-' 
        for lst in zip(week1, week2))
```